# Kaiwa XMPP Web Client usage with talk.google.com

Tags: linux, xmpp

I am using a debian server fresh install, got nodejs installed and working properly.

I can startup the server using "node server" :

```
dev environment detected
Client app ready
Cache manifest generated
Kaiwa running...
Hostname:<ip of the current server>
Port:8000
```

I can access the Kaiwa login page without any issue.

So, I modified the configuration file (which I can find no help anywhere and that here I have an issue for sure)

```
{
    "isDev": true,
    "http": {
        "host": "<ip of the current server>",
        "port": 8000
    },
    "session": {
        "secret": "shhhhhh don't tell anyone ok?"
    },
    "server": {
        "name": "talk",
        "domain": "talk.google.com",
        "wss": "wss://talk.google.com:5222/xmpp-websocket/",
        "muc": "",
        "startup": "groupchat/room%40chat.mydomain.net",
        "admin": "admin"
    }
}
~
```

So, the issue is that I cant login through Kaiwa to talk.google.com

Anybody tried to use this web client and succeeded in configuring it ?

Any help is very appreciated (Honestly I dont know much about XMPP and what above settings mean^^)

Thanks.